# Where would I start a discussion regarding new techniques for electronic/digital live performances?

Tags: discussion

### The discussion topic is below

"I want to hear other people's opinions on using Bare Conductive paint to paint "pads" on, probably, a guitar, connecting all of that to a Raspberry Pi/pisound, maybe some Arduinos, and writing a program that would work something like this;

- Touch this square (the "pad"), play this sound
- Slide your finger along this strip, adjust gain/tone/volume, etc.
- Move your finger along this bigg**er** square (XY Slider), control
  the way a synth sounds that is operated using a series of squares
  (possibly configure like a mini keyboard)
- Touch this other square to record a section, store it on pad 1, play it back automatically, touch pad 1 to mute, touch again to unmute

Things like that. The sliders would be complicated and probably require extra hardware that would go in the back of the guitar. The hardware would probably go in a case that is fitted to the guitar in such a way as to minimise the effect it would have if played acoustically."

### Would it be appropriate to ask this on the main site or should I wait until I have enough rep to start a chat room?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

discussion and opinion is not what Stack Exchange is designed for, so the general answer is "not on Stack Exchange"

So while you can use chat for this, it's not really suitable here.